# How to create a directory without root permission?

Tags: linux, shell, capistrano

I am trying to create a directory on the server through a *mina-deployer* script but the shell shows **Permission denied**.

The command is:

```
mkdir -p /monit && chown ubuntu: /monit && chmod u+w . /monit
```

And the error is:

```
Mkdir: unable to create directory "/ monit": Permission denied

queue 'echo "-----> Create Monit dir"'
queue echo_cmd "mkdir -p #{config_path}/monit && chown #{user}:#{group} #{config_path}/monit && chmod u+w . #{config_path}/monit"
```

Comment: Why is there a space in the output? Also if you're creating directories at the root you'll need to be `root` via `sudo` or some other method.

Comment: @tadman the space is from parameter     queue 'echo "-----> Create Monit dir"'
    queue echo_cmd "mkdir -p #{config_path}/monit && chown #{user}:#{group} #{config_path}/monit && chmod u+w . #{config_path}/monit"
    monitored.each do |p|
      path = "#{config_path}/monit/#{p}"
      queue echo_cmd "mkdir -p #{path} && chown #{user}:#{group} #{path} && chmod u+w . #{path}"

Comment: @tadman: You are right. Plus, "Mkdir" has an upper case *M*. Either the OP has not used copy&paste to show the error message, or the message does not come from from this statement. I guess it is the former.

Answer (score 3):

If you don’t have permission then you don’t have permission. You can either:

- Create the file elsewhere.
- Run the command as a different user (via `sudo`, `su`, or logging in as them) who does have the appropriate permission.
- Adjust the permissions of the enclosing directory (but take care doing so, as `/` and other places have their permissions as-is for good reason).

Comment: i have the permission. but i'm creating from deployment script

    queue 'echo "-----> Create Monit dir"'
    queue echo_cmd "mkdir -p #{config_path}/monit && chown #{user}:#{group} #{config_path}/monit && chmod u+w . #{config_path}/monit"
    monitored.each do |p|
      path = "#{config_path}/monit/#{p}"
      queue echo_cmd "mkdir -p #{path} && chown #{user}:#{group} #{path} && chmod u+w . #{path}"

Comment: @japoowf - if your question is about your script, include your script in your question. Don't put things like that in comments -- the formatting is terrible, and others will miss relevant details.